# Access Control Apache

Tags: apache, server, httpd.conf, mod-authz-host

Just having trouble setting an access control in Apache. So I want to deny access to a specific ip address for a section in my website. So when this ip address access my site, they shouldn't be able to see the "test" section of the website.

This is what I have done inside the httpd.conf file

```
<Directory /test>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from 10.13.89.47
</Directory>
```

Please can someone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you have provided, you document root is '/' (very dangerous) or you've not understood how the 'Directory' tag works. I would expect the tag to look something more like.....

```
<Directory /srv/www/htdocs/test>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used something else to get it working.

```
<Location/test>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from 10.13.89.47
</Location>
```